# No XMLBean Classes Generated for XSD and WSDL Files (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, xmlbeans, wsdl2code, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I ma trying to generate XMLBean classes for some XSD and WSDL that I have. My POM file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MySchemaFiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySchemaFiles</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MySchemaFiles</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/xmlbeans-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>

            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.3</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/xmlbeans-maven-plugin -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3.3</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles/</schemaDirectory>
                        <generatedSchemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generatedSchemaDirectory>
                        <outputJar>MySchemaFiles.jar</outputJar>
                        <classGenerationDirectory>${basedir}/target/java/classes/</classGenerationDirectory>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <sourceGenerationDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceGenerationDirectory>
                    </configuration>

                    <executions>

                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <quiet>false</quiet>
                                <staleFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/target/staleFile/</staleFile>
                                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles/</schemaDirectory>
                                <sourceGenerationDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceGenerationDirectory>
                                <classGenerationDirectory>${basedir}/target/java/classes/</classGenerationDirectory>
                                <compiler>1.8</compiler>
                            </configuration>
                            <inherited>true</inherited>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>

                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.9</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.7.9</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <executions>

                        <execution>
                            <id>genrate-wsdl-to-java</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/WSDLFiles/</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                                <wsdlFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/WSDLFiles/AtcProcessOrder.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                                <generateServerSide>false</generateServerSide>
                                <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <packageName>com.att.logicalprovisioning.atc.processorder</packageName>
                                <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                            </configuration>
                            <inherited>true</inherited>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>

                </plugin>

            </plugins>

        </pluginManagement>

    </build>

</project>
```

When I run:

```
mvn clean package -X
```

I do not see any errors, or at least nothing catches my eye, but there are absolutely no java classes generated. I trying to figure out what the problem is, but haven't been able to because of the lack of examples/documentations. I can switch to JAXB, but that is not an option. I have to stick to XMLBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only configured the plugins in `<pluginManagement>`. You need to also declare them in the `<plugins>` section (outside pluginManagement) so that they become part of your build.

Comment: Like this??:
`<build>

  <plugins>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>

   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  
  <pluginManagement>

   <plugins>

    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.3</version>
...... and so on`

Comment: You can do it that way, or you can configure the plugins in the pluginManagement, but you need to declare them with groupId and artifacatId again in the plugins section.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thanks that worked. Struggling with this for two days.